# How do I restart the scene that I'm currently in, through script in unity 2d so that it resets my sprites?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to find a script for unity 2d. I need one that restarts the scene I've currently loaded. I've tried a couple from the internet, but none of them seem to work. I just need the basic script, not any way to trigger it because I can do that myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to search Unity Documents first? Because the first thing you should see is 
[SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) class.  From this class you can just call [SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html). With this script you can restart active scene.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did:

```
void Start()
{
    Button Button = this.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button.onClick.AddListener(Reset);
}

public void Reset()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

It only takes in a build index

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to go through the [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) class in [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html).

However, you can use this line to reload the current scene thus, restarting it:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
```

Hope that answers your questions.

Comment: it seems like it should work according to the unity documents but, it doesn't seem to work. I'm triggering it on collision with another object. my collision script is:   private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
    }                                                                                                                                                                  This has worked with other collision things but not with the reload scene. I don't know if my code is the problem or yours.

Comment: Did you try verifying if your OnCollisionStay2D is even getting called or not? Try putting a Debug.Log("Collision") inside your collision function and check if it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.