# How do I make a restart button or use r for restarting the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

See when my player dies you can restart well that's what I wanted but I can't get it to work and I want it to where you have an option of either pressing r or the button to restart.

Can I please get a couple of tips for this probably some code too but that's up to you btw I am a beginner and need much help my game is just a basic learning game and I will love help from you fellow gamedevs

This is my old code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResetManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ResetManager Instance { get; private set; }

    public event System.Action ResetEvent = new delegate {};

    public void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public static void ResetScene()
    {
        Instance.ResetEvent();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if I could make it without scene manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851443/how-do-i-restart-the-scene-that-im-currently-in-through-script-in-unity-2d-so

Comment: no sir it dosnt i needed to know how to make a button the restart button to restart the scene thank you tho

Comment: The above comment shows you an exact line of code to restart a scene. You would insert that into your above code under `ResetScene()`. If you need to know how to set up a button, that is more "learning" than "debugging", and StackOverflow may not be the best place to go for that.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow, here I will show a brief tutorial on how to build the key in the UI as well as execute the reset code. To create a **UI button**, go to **Hierarchy** and right-click, you can create a Button from the UI menu as shown below.

[image]

After creating the button, attach the script to a Manager object, click the button and reference the reset command at the bottom of the event, as below, keeping in mind that the unity event does not support `static` method's.

```cs
public void ResetScene() => SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

[image]

After performing the above steps, your button will restart the scene when clicked.

---

You can also restart the scene when you press the <kbd>R</kbd> key by adding the following code.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) ResetScene();
}
```